# Load in data to Python from .mat that contains multiple structs for each id?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab, scipy

I have a large dataset in Matlab that I want to convert into a data frame in Python. The dataset is a 1*17 struct (one for each participant in an experiment). Each participant also has a struct with many variables that I am keen to analyze. So I am looking for a solution that helps me do this.

For Python, I found this documentation quite useful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Using this information I have loaded the .mat file into python with the following code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

matlabData = loadmat(r"\LPS_IMU_Struct060621_Done.mat")
data = matlabData['LPS_Struct']
data.dtype

# Which return this information:
# dtype([('Name', 'O'), ('Table', 'O'), ('Array', 'O'), ('Time', 'O'), ('IMU_Number', 'O'), ('Cutted_Array', 'O'), ('ArrayRotated', 'O'), ('RunIndex', 'O'), ('Run_New_Index', 'O'), ('ArrayRotatedMoved', 'O'), ('IMU_Table', 'O')])
```

But I don't understand what I should do next. A helpful resource I found was [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEBsiR6hImo). But it doesn't seem to work in my case because I a many structs for each person. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you state more clearly what's the issue you are trying to solve, please? Can you share a dummy mat file that mimics your real ones, please? Thanks!

Comment: that looks like a `structured array`. That's documented.  `data['Name']` accesses the 'name' field.  `data[0]` is the first 'record',

Comment: With 'O' (object) dtype it's hard to say what individual fields look like.  `loadmat` can only do so much to convert MATLAB structures into equivalent `numpy` ones.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not able to create a dummy data (I have tried). @hpaulj: I don't know if this a good solution but I tried: for a,b in enumerate(data[0,:]["Name"]):
  for c,d in enumerate(data[0,a]['Run_New_Index'][0,:], start=1):
    for e,f in enumerate(data[0,a]['Run_New_Index'][0,0]['LPS_Calculations'][0,0]['Trajectory_Time_Final'][:], start=1):

Comment: In other words: I used nested loops to fetch the data I want.